# Toggle visibility of all <pre> elements

Tags: html, css

How do I add a button or link to a page that would hide/show all `<pre>` elements when clicked? Is there a CSS-only solution, similar to http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-showhide? Is it possible to create a drop-in solution so that only a `<script>` element needs to be added to the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be hacked similarly to that CSS example you've shown, but I'm not too sure about cross-browser compatibility...

A simple standalone JS snippet will work though:

## Plain JS way:

```js
document.getElementById('t').addEventListener('click', toggle);

function toggle(){
  var pres = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
  for (var i = 0; i < pres.length; i++) {
    pres[i].style.display = pres[i].style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="t">Toggle</button>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
```

---

## The CSS-only way:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {display: none}
input[type=checkbox] ~ pre {
  display: block;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ pre{
    display: none;
}
label {cursor: pointer}
label:hover {font-weight: bold}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="t" role="button">
<label for="t">toggle</label>     
      
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
```

## @StephenP's way:

```js
document.getElementById('t').addEventListener('click', toggle);

function toggle(){
  var pres = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
  for (var i = 0; i < pres.length; i++) {
    pres[i].classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {display: none}
```

```html
<button id="t">Toggle</button>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
<pre>pre</pre>
```

So the idea is that a class (`hidden`) is taking care of visibility, and you're no longer directly changing the `display` style of the elements, but just adding/removing the `hidden` class.

This is a much better approach for styling elements in 99% cases.

Comment: Thanks. What are your concerns about compatibility, which browsers would be supported?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure about the tilde (`~`) selector, will need to check.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a CSS-only version based on your example... Still not sure whether I'd use it.

Comment: Nice. Since I prefer doing this sort of thing with classes, I tend to use something like `pres[i].classList.toggle('showing')` when using javascript, rather than manipulate the display style itself.

Comment: Absolutely, @StephenP!!! I just didn't want to go outside of the question scope, thank you for adding it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the CSS solution. I have only limited control over the HTML (it's autogenerated), better designs are possible for sure. -- To sum up my limited understanding: CSS-only is hacky and requires new browsers, JavaScript is simpler (although I don't understand `classList` in Stephen's code example), and probably JavaScript also would be required to make it a true drop-in solution that *also adds a button to the body* (if I parse [this reference](http://andydavies.me/blog/2012/08/13/what-if-we-could-use-css-to-manipulate-html-attributes/) correctly).

Comment: According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), the tilde (`~`) operator is supported is all relevant browsers... For some reason, I didn't expect that, but it seems like the CSS-only solution is just fine if you don't mind polluting the markup a bit.

Comment: @Shomz: When reading the original example, I was wondering why the checkbox is not selected via `id`. Is there a specific reason for this? -- **EDIT**: No, selecting via `id` also seems to work fine. Would that resolve the "markup pollution" argument?

Comment: @krlmlr [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a cool newer DOM element feature, but you may need [a polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js) to get support in your target browsers.

Comment: @StephenP, I think `className` might work for those antique browsers.

Comment: @krlmlr, the markup pollution actually refers to all the elements in the markup, not just the visible ones. So, you have an extra `input` and its `label`... it doesn't matter how you select them. That's why I called that solution a hack.

Comment: And yes, for the full drop-in solution, you'd need to know inside what element to place the button and then you can simply do: `var button = document.createElement('button'); button.addEventListener('click', toggle); someParentElement.appendChild(button);`

Comment: @Shomz: Wonderful, thank you! I'd still use a plain CSS file to style the button and define the `.hidden` class, right?

Comment: Exactly, you can put an id or a class on that button (or even use just the button CSS selector, if that's the only button) and style it. Technically, you can get away without a separate CSS file, by using the `style` tag directly inside the HTML, but that's even more pollution. You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: `className` would work on old browsers, but (1) you'd have to test-and-toggle it yourself, and (2) you'd need further code of your own if you needed to support multiple classes on the elements. Having written that (2) before, I prefer the available shim. (After all the edits I feel I should be allowed to upvote your answer another time)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with this jquery code: `$("pre").toggle()`, added within a [click handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for your button. And yes, only a `<script>` tag is needed in your header, however I'd recommend adding the tag at the end of the body, for html rendering performance improvements.

Alternatively you can use `show()` and `hide()` if you want better control of when to hide and when to show.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery you'll need 2 script tags; one for jquery and one for attaching your handler. In that case you may as well put them both in the _<head>_ and use jQuery's `$(document).ready( ... )`, that way you don't have to modify both the top and the bottom of your page file — it's all done in one place.